# npm ERR! Failed at the mysomm-client@0.1.0 start script

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have encountered an error for which I have little causal information, but I will provide as much context as I can.

I created a simple React application, and my error is exclusive to my client side directory where node_modules is installed.  My app worked as recently as 2 weeks ago, yet when I run the command 'npm start', the app fails to launch. The npm generated error response in my terminal is describing: "npm ERR! Failed at the mysomm-client@0.1.0 start script."

```
davidcarrillojr@Davids-MBP mysomm-client % npm start

> mysomm-client@0.1.0 start /Users/davidcarrillojr/Desktop/projects/mern_projects/MySomm/mysomm-client
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: /Users/davidcarrillojr/Desktop/projects/mern_projects/MySomm/mysomm-client/public
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mysomm-client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mysomm-client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/davidcarrillojr/.npm/_logs/2020-09-15T21_34_39_443Z-debug.log
davidcarrillojr@Davids-MBP mysomm-client %
```

Debug Log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v14.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle mysomm-client@0.1.0~prestart: mysomm-client@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle mysomm-client@0.1.0~start: mysomm-client@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle mysomm-client@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle mysomm-client@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/davidcarrillojr/Desktop/projects/mern_projects/MySomm/mysomm-client/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
9 verbose lifecycle mysomm-client@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Users/davidcarrillojr/Desktop/projects/mern_projects/MySomm/mysomm-client
10 silly lifecycle mysomm-client@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle mysomm-client@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle mysomm-client@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: mysomm-client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid mysomm-client@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/davidcarrillojr/Desktop/projects/mern_projects/MySomm/mysomm-client
16 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v14.0.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error mysomm-client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the mysomm-client@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

The terminal response indicates it can't located a file 'index.html', however I have never used an index.htm file ever since I created this project.

I have not altered any directories or files since the project was originally created. Nor have I changed any front-end code or files since the app last ran successfully approximately two weeks ago.

*This is my first post to stackoverflow, if anyone has any tips on posting a most descriptive question, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

The public directory and it's 'index.html' file were moved to another directory so when the react-script start ran, it could not complete the script without the public/index.html replicated again.  I was actually able to track my github repo tree to get a copy of the misplace file.